# Simple Antivirus Live-USB

Tags: windows, anti-virus

I'm looking for a simple (click-and-create, click-and-run) live-USB anti-virus solution that can scan windows partitions, and can be easily updated.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

http://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/clamwin_portable

Comment: Thats not bootable.

Comment: but it works great with any bootable windows Live CD, UBCD or any of those. I agree that its a valid comment.

Answer (score 1):

You could try Trinity Rescue Kit, basically a command-line, livecd based utility

It gives you 5 antivirus programs, autoupdate, and a so many other tools. And it's bootable.

http://trinityhome.org/Home/index.php?wpid=1&front_id=12

Answer (score 1):

[Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) has a few to select from such as Dr Web, Kaspersky and F-Secure. It will download an iso, and create a liveusb for you. You might also be able to use this on your own ISOs of various AV livecds if they are casper based

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Ultimate Boot CD](http://www.ubcd4win.com/) for Windows. It has an option of choosing a USB instead of CD.

Answer (score 0):

Try [slax](http://www.slax.org/) with [klamav](http://www.slax.org/modules.php?action=detail&id=2288) module, it can be run both from CD or USB

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Sandisk USB or an U3 USB, it usually has an option to install a portable version of Avast (Home Edition) on it.